# php create certificate signing request into file error/warning

Tags: php, openssl

I need to create a certificate signing request to file but last line give error when run:

```
Warning: openssl_csr_export_to_file() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Any idea? this is the code, it's php 7.04 - wamp.

```
    <?php
    $subject = array(
    "commonName" => "example.com",
    );
    $private_key = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    "config" => "C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.0.4/extras/ssl/openssl.cnf",
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
    ));

    $csr = openssl_csr_new($subject, $private_key, array('digest_alg' => 
    'sha384') );
     openssl_pkey_export_to_file($private_key, 'example-priv.key');
     // Along with the subject, the CSR contains the public key corresponding to    
     // the private key
    openssl_csr_export_to_file($csr, 'example-csr.pem');
```

Comment: Look at the manual for `openssl_csr_new`. It returns `false` if it fails. You haven't checked for that so later calls get a Boolean when they expect a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected:

```
$subject = array(
    "commonName" => "example.com",
);

// vars to make private key
$private_key = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
));

// in config you put path to openssl.cnf
$Configs = array(       
    'config' => 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.0.4/extras/ssl/openssl.cnf',
    'digest_alg' => 'sha2',
    'x509_extensions' => 'v3_ca',
    'req_extensions' => 'v3_req',
    'encrypt_key' => true,
    'encrypt_key_cipher' => OPENSSL_CIPHER_3DES
);

$csr = openssl_csr_new($subject , $private_key,  $Configs );

openssl_pkey_export_to_file($private_key, 'priv.key');

// openssl_csr_export_to_file($csr, 'example-csr.pem');
// better to specify path
openssl_csr_export_to_file($csr, 'C:/wamp/example-csr.pem' );

/*
or view it:
openssl_csr_export($csr, $csrout);  //  and var_dump($csrout);
echo $csrout;
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved but not sure yet if all steps result in correct keys/files (someone can look at it?):

```
<?php
echo '<pre>'; error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$dn = array(
    "countryName" => "GB",
    "stateOrProvinceName" => "Greater London",
    "localityName" => "London",
    "organizationName" => "XY Ltd",
    "emailAddress" => "ab@xy.com"
);

$Configs = array(       
    'config' => 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.0.4/extras/ssl/openssl.cnf',
    'digest_alg' => 'sha2',
    'x509_extensions' => 'v3_ca',
    'req_extensions' => 'v3_req',
    'encrypt_key' => true,
    'encrypt_key_cipher' => OPENSSL_CIPHER_3DES
);

$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new([
    "config" => "C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.0.4/extras/ssl/openssl.cnf",
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
]);

openssl_pkey_export($privateKey, $privKey, null, [
    "config" => "C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.0.4/extras/ssl/openssl.cnf",
]);

$a_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);

// print_r($a_key);
// print_r($privKey); // Just to test output

file_put_contents('keys/public.key', $a_key['key']);
file_put_contents('keys/private.pem', $privKey);

$csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $private_key, $Configs);
// var_dump($csr);

openssl_csr_export_to_file($csr, 'C:/wamp/www/php/keys/public.csr' );

openssl_free_key($privateKey);
```